# Publish a AppScript Project as a webApp from the same Script file

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to create a method, with which I can publish a appScript code as a webapp from the same script file.
Though there are REST api to do the same, I am trying to figure out a wat to do it though appScript it self.

Comment: I believe there are Google Documentations - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy a [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) from any script project, including a script project that is bound to a Docs Editor file such as a spreadsheet.

See the [Web App Demo](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/153204/embed-an-interactive-calculator-in-my-website-using-google-sheets) answer for more information and sample code.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

*There is no method within the [ScriptApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app) class to deploy.*

### Work-around

You can make an API call to the [projects.deployments.create](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.deployments/create) method with the [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) class. In order to make a successful call you must activate the [Apps Script API](https://script.google.com/home/usersettings).

```
var scriptId = 'some id'
var url = `https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${scriptId}/deployments`

var formData = {
  "versionNumber": 1,
  "description": "DeployFromApi",
  "manifestFileName": "appsscript"
}

var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
  'payload' : formData
};
UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', options);
```